# Error when trying to initialize a union inside a struct

Tags: c++, struct, return, unions

So I a function which returns a pointer to a struct (`parse_files_result_t*`). This struct contains a union:

```
struct parse_files_result_t{
    result_tag tag;
    union {
        struct parse_file_error_t *err_ptr;
        struct parse_file_response_t *ok_ptr;        
    } data;
};
```

And I wanted to use the union to return an `*err_ptr` or an `*ok_ptr` based on the calculations in the function.

So I wrote the following code:

```
parse_files_result_t* result = (parse_files_result_t*)malloc(sizeof (parse_files_result_t));

if (success) {        
    parse_file_response_t response = //data
    *result = parse_file_result_t{result_tag::Ok, result->data.ok_ptr = &response};
    return result;
} else {
    parse_file_error_t errorresponse = //data
    *result = parse_files_result_t{{result_tag::Err}, {result->data.err_ptr = &errorresponse}};
    return result;
}
```

So far so good. The `else` part, where a `parse_file_error_t` gets returned, works fine because the `parse_file_error_t` is the first part of the union. In the `if` part, I want to return only the `parse_file_response_t`. Because this is the second "part" of the union, I get this error:

> error: cannot convert ‘parse_file_response_t*’ to ‘parse_file_error_t*’ in initialization

Even though I wrote `result->data.ok_ptr`, my compiler tries to put the `parse_file_response_t response` into the `parse_file_error_t` part of the union.

How can I fix this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `*result = parse_file_response_t{...}` is wrong. Please make sure you have a proper [mcve] to show us.

Comment: Also please don't use `malloc` to allocate memory in C++. If you need to use pointers then first of all use smart pointers (like `std::unique_ptr`) and always use `new` to allocate objects.

Comment: Lastly, the variables `response` and `errorresponse` are *local* variables. When the `if` respective `else` bodies end, so does the lifetime of those objects, and any pointer to them will become invalid.

Comment: You are assigning one type to unrelated type, your union consists of 2 different pointer types, one is not assignable to another.

Comment: Why not use `std::variant`?

Comment: @metablaster The assignments are to different union members.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `*ptr = type{args}` is not necessarily wrong.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings It is if `type` isn't the same as (or implicitly convertible to) the type of `*ptr`. Which is most likely the case here (I doubt that `parse_file_response_t` is convertible to `parse_files_result_t`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oh yeah :D

Comment: @JaMiT yes I made a mistake there - thanks for noticing it.

Comment: @WernerHenze thanks for the tip - problem for me here was that I have to use the signature of the `parse_file_result_t` struct and so I have to use the union

Comment: Samuel Dressel, it was actually @Someprogrammerdude who noticed it. ;)

Comment: I just saw it - thanks to @Someprogrammerdude :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Even though I wrote `result->data.ok_ptr`, my compiler tries to put the `parse_file_response_t response` into the `parse_file_error_t` part of the union.

Well, yes. You compacted so much into a single line, you lost track of what you are telling the computer to do.

> ```
>    *result = parse_files_result_t{result_tag::Ok, result->data.ok_ptr = &response};
> ```

This statement does several things. *(Work from the inside out to follow along. We'll start from `result->data.ok_ptr = &response` and work out to `*result = [stuff]`.)*

1. Assign the address of `response` to `result->data.ok_ptr`.
2. A (temporary) `parse_files_result_t` object is constructed using the initial values `result_tag::Ok` and the value that was assigned in step 1. These values are assigned to the `tag` and `data.err_ptr` members, hence the error.
3. Assign the object constructed in step 2 to `*result`, overwriting the assignment that was done in step 1.

Simplify your code to (almost) get what you want.

```
    result->tag = result_tag::Ok;
    result->data.ok_ptr = &response;
```

This gives more lines of code, but the syntax is clearer. Also, you are creating less work for the computer since this no longer tries to create a temporary `parse_files_result_t` object.

There is still a problem, though, in that `result->data.ok_ptr` will be a dangling pointer. Unfortunately, I think addressing that (and addressing the other issues) goes outside the scope of your question.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer - this helped me alot.